# regex look-behind: Invalid regular expression: /(?<=\.)\S+$/: Invalid group

Tags: javascript, regex

I have the following regexp

```
(?<=\.)\S+$
```

used to extract the extension (whatever comes after the last dot) of a string. [**regex101.com**](https://regex101.com/r/aV8sY8/1) seems to accept my regexp: the string extension is correctly matched. As soon as I move it into a javascript script and try to test it against a string I get this error:

```
Invalid regular expression: /(?<=\.)\S+$/: Invalid group
```

I get the same error also with regex101 auto generated code:

```
var re = /(?<=\.)\S+$/; 
var str = 'test.txt';
var m;

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    // View your result using the m-variable.
    // eg m[0] etc.
}
```

see fiddle [**HERE**](https://jsfiddle.net/m959scy6/)

Any hint?

Comment: Just a note for the future in the top left section of regex101 it says "flavors" and you can select Javascript instead of PCRE to see that look behinds aren't valid

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You cannot use look-behinds in JavaScript regex. There are some [JavaScript look-behind workarounds](http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript), but they all have their own handicaps. To play it safe, use capturing groups. Here, the contents you need will be in the 2nd group:

```
  (\.)([^.]+)$
```

Or, with just 1 capturing group (to increase performance):

```
  \.([^.]+)$
```

Code:

```js
var re = /\.([^.]+)$/; 
var str = 'test.txt';
var m;

if ((m = re.exec(str)) !== null) {
    if (m.index === re.lastIndex) {
        re.lastIndex++;
    }
    alert(m[1]);
}
```

Comment: No, I don't :) It is just for illustration.

Comment: didn't know that, thanks. Is there any piece of documentation about this?

Comment: That captures everything after the first dot, should there be more than one.

Comment: @mintsauce: It is a good point, we should limit to everything that is not a period. Answer updated.

Comment: @BeNdErR: I guess you can find a lot on JavaScript lookarounds here, on SO, or have a look at MDN Regex reference (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp). If you are specifically interested in workarounds, here is a good resource: http://blog.stevenlevithan.com/archives/mimic-lookbehind-javascript.

Answer (score 0):

Due to babel-loader error

Replace `var re = /(?<=\.)\S+$/;` with `var re = new RegExp("(?<=\\.)\\S+$");`